# I need to make a unix script to read first word from a file

Tags: unix

I need to make a unix script to read first word from a file, and if that is "Mon,Tue....Sat,Sun" then it will print echo 0 or else echo 1

I was trying with grep command but it didn't worked

Comment: Please provide information regarding what you've already tried script wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try egrep command like:

```
head -1 myfile.txt | egrep '^[Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat] .*'; echo $?
```

Comment: If possible can u give me an exmaple how to add if statement in that...   i.e. if the first word is Sun-Sat then it will print 0 or else it will print "No Header"....

Comment: Something like `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo 0; else print "No Header"; fi`

Answer (score 2):

When you need to parse input for words **awk** is better then grep, it still can do what grep does, but also can precess every line with simple scripts.

This is my take on solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{c=0} $1~/Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat/{c=1} END{print c}' test.txt
```

I encourage you to learn more about awk in [this (short) tutorial](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html)

Answer (score 2):

This could even be done without `grep` or `awk`, using just `bash` builtins (assuming your shell is `bash` - this should also work in `ksh` and also `zsh`, and maybe in `sh`, but not `csh`, where the syntax is quite a bit different):

```
read firstword otherstuff < myfile.txt
case "${firstword}" in
  Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat) echo 1;;
  *) echo 0;;
esac
```

You could also use regexp matching to avoid the `case` statement (this is definitely `bash`-only, though):

```
if [[ "${firstword}" =~ ^(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)$ ]]; then
```

That's just a matter of preference, though...

Comment: good stuff as always, but to clarify slightly, any ksh that responds to `echo ${.sh.version}` will also support your `=~` example. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Good to know... I haven't worked with any more-recent `ksh` versions recently, so I wasn't aware of that...